# AWS PUT request met with "Provided key element does not match schema."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, put

(Edited to incorporate comments)
So I apologize in advance for the long question. I don't know how else to ask it.
I'm trying to finish up a full-stack web app using React, Node, and DynamoDB. POST and GET requests are working fine, but I'm stuck on PUT. My mock PUT request works fine, but once I try it from the front end in React, I get the error mentioned in the title. I'll show the back end code first, then the mock update, and then the front end.

```
import handler from "./libs/handler-lib";
import dynamoDb from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";

export const main = handler(async (event, context) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.tableName,
    Key: {
      userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      activityId: event.pathParameters.activityId
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET title = :title, activityType = :activityType, activityRoutine = :activityRoutine, activityComment = :activityComment",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":title": data.title || null,
      ":activityType": data.activityType || null,
      // ":activityRoutine": data.activityRoutine == '' ? "None" : data.activityRoutine,
      // ":activityComment": data.activityComment == '' ? "None" : data.activityComment
      ":activityRoutine": data.activityRoutine || null,
      ":activityComment": data.activityComment || null
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW" 
  };

  await dynamoDb.update(params);
  return { status: true };
```

This mock update event works without issue:

```
{
    "body": "{\"title\":\"test\",\"activityType\":\"testing\",\"activityRoutine\":\"\",\"activityComment\":\"\"}",
    "pathParameters": {
      "activityId": "long-alphanumeric-id"
    },
    "requestContext": {
      "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityId": "us-east-and-so-on"
      }
    }
  }
```

But this code, which produces the exact same Javascript object as the mock, is not okay with AWS:

```
 function saveActivity(activity) {
    try {
      return API.put("activities", `/activities/${id}`, {
        body: activity
      });

    } catch(e) {
      console.log("saveActivity error:", e);  
    }
  }

  async function handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true)
      try {
        await saveActivity({
          title: title, activityType: activityType, activityRoutine: activityRoutine, activityComment: activityComment
          // "key": {userId: userId, activityId: activityId}
          // "pathParameters": {"id": activityId},
          // "requestContext": {"identity": {"cognitoIdentityId": userId}}
        });
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
        setIsLoading(false)
      }
    }
```

If anyone needs to see more of the code, I'm happy to share, but I figured this question is already getting very long. Any code you see commented out has been tried before without success.
I'd also be happy if someone could point me in the right direction as far as the AWS documentation is concerned. I've been going off of a tutorial and modifying it where need be.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems like your PUT body, has `body`, `pathParameters`, and `requestContext`.  The body of the PUT request from your frontend should only have the contents of `body`.  The other params are added to the lambda event by API Gateway.

Comment: Just the body was how I started. I only added in the ``pathParameters`` and ``requestContext`` because the error message was regarding the key element. I tried it again just to make sure I didn't miss something, but sure enough, I deleted everything but the body and I get the same error message.

Comment: Log the event your lambda is receiving and compare it to the mock event. One thing I just noticed is that in your mock event the path param is `id` but in your handler you're using `pathParameters.activityId`.  The name of the parameter will come from the API Gateway configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm logging the event in lambda properly. You were right; it's definitely ```activityId```, not ```id```. How do I see what ```pathParameters``` lambda is receiving?

Comment: I'm looking in the Chrome developer tools, and I see the request payload in the headers, along with the `x-amzn-requestid` and tons of other stuff, but no `pathParameters`.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-logging.html you can `console.log(event)` in the handler, and inspect the logs in CloudWatch

Comment: I've looked in CloudWatch, and I've already included `console.log(event)` and it's basically all stuff that I can see in the Chrome dev tools. No matter what I log, I can't see the actual `pathParameters` being sent. Same goes for any API call. I'm never able to see the userId and activityId, which didn't really matter with my other requests, because I never got an error regarding my `key element`, but now there's clearly something wrong with the keys I'm sending to my API, but I have no idea what I'm sending.

Comment: I created an example [here](https://imgur.com/a/WV7apc2) to show how the API Gateway configuration impacts the event the Lambda is receiving and how you can inspect the event in the CloudWatch logs.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I changed the mock event when I should have paid closer attention to my handler. The problem wasn't activityId per se. The problem was the pathParameters attribute. I had `event.pathParameters.activityId` when it should have been `event.pathParameters.id`. It's like that in my GET handler. I just completely overlooked it. Want to do the honors of answering it and I'll accept it?

Comment: No worries, happy you were able to figure it out